# Is it possible to contain a button with respect to the bottom, rather than the top element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

So I am currently using constraint layout for my signup screen. However, the signup button is supposed to be like 100dp from parent bottom, rather than `200 dp` from the top element. Whenever I try to remove the top margin and try to make it relative to the parent bottom, it ends up in almost the middle of the screen instead of the bottom. I was wondering if there's a way I can make it such that it aligns to the bottom of the screen? 
Here's my code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/image_gradient"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/hero_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_white_logo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/reddish"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/link_sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:text="@string/no_account"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

From the above XML, button login_in and sign_up link are supposed to be together (which works as expected), login button, below that signup link. But I am manually setting `"android:layout_marginTop="200dp"`
from the logo on top of it, which is not a good practice, as for some devices, it does not end up aligning to the bottom as expected (and is hardcoded). Rather I would like it to say `100dp` from the margin with no alliance to the top, so for any device, it's `100dp` from the bottom. Any ideas on how to fix this to achieve the goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `value/dimention`  with specify resolution

Comment: If you use `ConstraintLayout` Maybe you would like to use [Guidlines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to replace your fixed size margins and make your screen responsive to all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same behaviour using a `RelativeLayout` like the following.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:letterSpacing="0.07"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:letterSpacing="0.07"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
            android:text="No Account"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note that I have omitted some drawables and colors to test it in my IDE. Please modify as necessary.

Comment: is it not possible to do this with constraint layout?

Comment: Surely it is. However, I prefer `RelativeLayout` in this case for cleaner implementation.

Comment: thanks, I will test it out. Also, I am using this throughout my app, do you know of what i am missing in my code that can help me align it to the bottom ? would be really helpful instead of changing the code throughout my app! thanks! i appreciate your help!

Comment: Great to know that I could help. :)

Comment: Reaz any idea about this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937736/how-do-i-set-my-status-bar-transparent-but-keep-by-navigation-bar-black ?

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the question whenever I can manage some time. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Using Constraintlayout it's possible and better to use constraintlayout.Just give your constraint proper.
>   Also show your design which ever you want to do.
>   Here I do approx design

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="my_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pass"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:text="sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/link_sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:text="no_account"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```