# How do I set my status bar transparent but keep by navigation bar black?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

As my question suggests, I am trying to figure out how to set my status bar color transparent while keeping my navigation bar black/natural color (without affecting the screen height)
I referred to this site :
[Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)
one of the solutions that partially worked was :

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

but that pushes my screen content below navigation bar making it transparent. I want the screen size to remain the same while keeping the navigation bar its natural color. Just want to make the status bar transparent, but seems like all other ways make it off-white even when I set it transparent with (`setstatusbarcolor` option).

Any ideas on how to go about it? My **min SDK version is 23**.

[image: The first view without doing anything]

The second view is the view after adding the code above where the status bar works but the screen slides below making the nav bar transparent as well (even setting `fitsSystemWindows = false` doesn't help).

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not quite sure about the problem yet. It would be great if you could add some pictures of what you have right now and what do you want.

Comment: Can you please check my answer and let me know if that was your problem?

Comment: no luck with that :(, let me attach screenshots

Comment: @ReazMurshed added screenshots above, hope that makes it clear

Comment: The screenshots are perfect. Thanks for attaching them. :)

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I hope that solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following style in your activity theme.

In the `styles.xml` find the theme of your activity and add the following. As the minimum SDK version is 23 in your case, you do not need to worry about the previous versions of Android.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Here is the screenshot of what I have got.

[image]

Here's the theme style that I have in my case.

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: will it apply throughout the app? I am looking to apply it to just one activity. Rest of the activities are fine. Let me know if this will affect anything else

Comment: Nope. This just affects one single activity. If you have the same theme attached to other activities, then it will affect the others. However, you may consider creating a separate theme for this activity having this kind of behaviors.

Comment: the min sdk version for my app is 23 . do i still need to separate out values-v21? also, i added the above code in my styles and references that as     style="@style/SignupActivity"
 in my activity. no luck.

Comment: Oh ... if you have the SDK 23, then add the code for the `values-21` in your normal `styles.xml` file and yes, of course, you do not need another folder for `v-21`. I have a similar setting here I suppose and its working in my case.

Comment: strange.not sure why its causing an issue for me.have the same layout as you posted in the other question.i wonder if theres a missing link somewhere

Comment: I have added my test project here in Github - https://github.com/masudias/so-playground , please run the code to check if that works in your side. You can check the `MainActivity` and the theme used in the `MainActivity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Hi @MarissaNicholas, so are you still getting the problem? If you still have the problem, let me know.

Comment: Hi Reaz I havent tested it today, will test it later and let you know if it works!

Comment: Great to know that helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do below mentioned things may help you in your example. Let me if you still facing issue. If it will solve your issue then please provided answer.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```java
<activity
   ....            
   android:theme="@style/TranslucentStatusBarTheme">
</activity>
```

`values-v23\styles.xml`

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="TranslucentStatusBarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`Activity.java`

```java
private static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, boolean on) {
    Window win = activity.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check if the version of Android is Marshmallow or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int newUiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    // Check if the version of Android is Lollipop or higher
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        setWindowFlag(this, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorTranslucent));
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```